# how to get the latest datetime when nft was purchased?

Tags: transactions, nft

I have had success to get the datetime when NFT minted, but now I want to try to get the latest time when this NFT was purchased.

to get minted NFT I use this code :

```
const fetchGetNftMintDate = async (connection: Connection, pubkey: PublicKey) => {
  const txList  = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubkey)
  const unixTime = txList[txList.length-1].blockTime
  const oldestTxTimestamp = dayjs.unix(unixTime)
  return oldestTxTimestamp
}
```

now, how to get the latest datetime when NFT was purchased?

Comment: what do you mean by "latest datetime"?

Answer (score 1):

Consider Helius's [NFT sale transaction](https://docs.helius.dev/solana-apis/enhanced-transactions-api/parsed-transaction-history#nft-sale-transaction-example) api endpoint.